# What is a definitive discrete PID controller equation?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control

I need the equation of a discrete PID controller and I find different answers from different websites. For example, [here](http://portal.ku.edu.tr/~cbasdogan/Courses/Robotics/projects/Discrete_PID.pdf) the answer is:

$$u[k] = u[k-1] + (K_p + K_i \frac{T_s}{2} + \frac{K_d}{T_s}) e[k] + (-K_p + K_i \frac{T_s}{2} - 2 \frac{K_d}{T_s}) e[k-1] + \frac{K_d}{T_s} e[k-2]$$

and that's the equation that is used in [this](http://dspace.ucuenca.edu.ec/bitstream/123456789/21401/1/IEE_17_Romero%20et%20al.pdf) paper, for example. If I write that equation in function of $T_i$ ($T_i = K_p/K_i$) and $T_d$ ($T_d = K_d/K_p)$, I get:

$$u[k] = u[k-1] + K_p \left[ (1+\frac{T_s}{2 T_i} + \frac{T_d}{T_s}) e[k] + (-1 + \frac{T_s}{2 T_i} - 2 \frac{T_d}{T_s}) e[k-1] + \frac{T_d}{T_s} e[k-2]\right]$$

But in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) and in [this](http://dspace.ucuenca.edu.ec/bitstream/123456789/21401/1/IEE_17_Romero%20et%20al.pdf) paper (although they say they're using the written equation above) they use the following equation:

$$u[k] = u[k-1] + (K_p + \frac{K_d}{T_s}) e[k] + (-K_p - 2 \frac{K_d}{T_s}) e[k-1] + \frac{K_d}{T_s} e[k-2]$$

and I think that [here](http://ipco-co.com/PET_Journal/Papers%20CEIT%2714/248.pdf) they use the same equation.

So, what can I do? Which do I implement? Any demonstration?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your third term to actually match the Wikipedia article -- you left out the $K_i$ term entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The second equation is just the first equation with $K_i=0$. So the second equation would be a PD controller, while the first is PID controller.

One can derive the first equation by starting with common approximations for the integral $i[k]$ and derivative $d[k]$ terms

\begin{align}
i[k] &= i[k-1] + T_s\,\frac{e[k] + e[k-1]}{2}, \tag{1} \\
d[k] &= \frac{e[k] - e[k-1]}{T_s}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

The control signal could then also be constructed using

$$
u[k] = K_p\,e[k] + K_i\,i[k] + K_d\,d[k]. \tag{3}
$$

Your first equation can be obtained using the difference of the control signal and substituting $(1)$ and $(2)$

$$
u[k] - u[k-1] = 
\left(K_p\,e[k] + K_i\left(i[k-1] + T_s\,\frac{e[k] + e[k-1]}{2}\right) + K_d\,\frac{e[k] - e[k-1]}{T_s}\right) - 
\left(K_p\,e[k-1] + K_i\,i[k-1] + K_d\,\frac{e[k-1] - e[k-2]}{T_s}\right), \tag{4}
$$

namely expanding and simplifying this yields the same as your first equation

$$
u[k] - u[k-1] = 
\left(K_p + \frac{K_i\,T_s}{2} + \frac{K_d}{T_s}\right) e[k] + 
\left(-K_p + \frac{K_i\,T_s}{2} - \frac{2\,K_d}{T_s}\right) e[k-1] + 
\frac{K_d}{T_s} e[k-2]. \tag{5}
$$

The advantage of using $(5)$ over the combination of $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ is that $(5)$ uses less computations and memory. However for debugging the other implementation might be more convenient, since $i[k]$ and $d[k]$ would be directly available. This would make it for example easier to check for integral windup or whether the derivative is staying within certain desired bounds.

---

However as TimWescott mentioned, the derivative term from $(2)$ can also be approximated with

$$
d[k] = \frac{1 + \alpha}{T_s} (e[k] - e[k-1]) - \alpha\,d[k-1], \tag{6}
$$

with $-1\leq\alpha\leq1$. Namely for values close to zero the magnitude of the transfer function associated with $(6)$ stays closer to that of a true derivative but the phase does drop significantly at high frequencies, while for values close to one the phase stays closer to 90° but the magnitude can increase a lot at high frequencies. It can be noted that $\alpha=1$ is equivalent to the [bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform). For negative values the transfer function looks like a high pass filter (pure derivative filtered by a low pass filter), which has the advantage of not amplifying high frequency noise. A similar thing could also be done for the integral, however the effects of an integral should only affect low frequencies, which is hardly affected by changing the parameter $\alpha$.

Using $(6)$ instead of $(2)$ does not allow for $(4)$ to be simplified down to $(5)$, due to the added pole from $(6)$, however one can write it into the following combined difference equation

$$
u[k] + (\alpha - 1)\,u[k-1] - \alpha\,u[k-2] = 
\left(K_p + \frac{K_i\,T_s}{2} + \frac{K_d\,(1 + \alpha)}{T_s}\right) e[k] +
\left(K_p\,(\alpha - 1) + \frac{K_i\,T_s\,(\alpha + 1)}{2} - \frac{2\,K_d\,(1 + \alpha)}{T_s}\right) e[k-1] +
\left(-K_p\,\alpha + \frac{K_i\,T_s\,\alpha}{2} + \frac{K_d\,(1 + \alpha)}{T_s}\right) e[k-2]. \tag{7}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I prefer none of the above.  This works better, in my experience.  If you work out the math, you'll find that it's equivalent if you set $d_d = 0$.

$$u_d[k] = (1-d_d)(e[k]-e[k-1]) + d_d u_d[k-1] \\
  u_i[k] = e[k] + u_i[k] \\
  u[k] = k_i u_i[k] + k_p u[k] + k_d u_d[k]$$

Note that I've introduced the $d_d$ term -- this has the effect of band-limiting the derivative term (the closer $d_d$ is to 1, the slower the derivative), which will save you a world of grief from high-frequency oscillations.

Comment: and how did you get to that equation?

Comment: It's a set of difference equations that go with a controller with the transfer function $\frac{k_i z}{z - 1} + k_p + k_d \frac{(1-d)(z - 1)}{z - d}$.  It comes from almost 30 years of designing motion control systems that Actually Work(TM).

Comment: But can you please share with me any link or something where that equation is demonstrated?

Comment: [An article](http://wescottdesign.com/articles/pid/pidWithoutAPhd.pdf).  It's up on the Embedded Systems Programming site, somewhere, maybe, but they keep moving it so I keep one on my site.  Also these three videos: [What is a PID controller?](https://youtu.be/2elEXcv0AV8); [PID Controller in Software](https://youtu.be/JVqJ7uRGwoA); and [PID Tuning](https://youtu.be/drYO60z6_h4).